# IBM conversation still works with botframework?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I followed this tutorial [chatbot with watson conversation + botframwork](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chatbot-with-watson-conversation-using-microsoft-botframework/) to build a chatbot using bot framework with watson conversation. It worked just fine in the emulator, however when I add the Microsoft App Id and Password it stops responding. When I am working on the Azure Portal the bot ceases responding on web chat testing when I change the message endpoint (https://[myapp].bluemix.net/api/messages). Is there still a problem going on with the endpoint messages or the emulator?

Comment: I haven't looked at the code recently, but there was an SDK change for conversation where `message_input` was changed to `input` for argument on the message call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue with changing messaging endpoints on bots via the Azure Portal, though I was just trying to use ngrok. If you change the endpoint, the bot does in fact, cease to respond. The work around for this is to put your Microsoft AppId and AppPassword in your bot code, to validate it.

I'm not sure how Watson works, but for BotBuilder node.js bots, the code below is what you have to do to connect the non-azure code to the bot endpoint:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder')
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
```

[Here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.chatconnector.html) is the link to bot-builder's ChatConnector in the documentation so you can see exactly what it does, and find a way to implement it in your Watson code.

Comment: I have done what you mentioned, the tutorial I followed is this one: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chatbot-with-watson-conversation-using-microsoft-botframework/. I can see on the logs that the bot gets what I say and reply to it, but the answers don't show on the Skype bot created.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'reply to it'?

Comment: Well, just to close my question. My bot started responding, I didn't make any changes.